# Как правильно перегрузить оператор умножения числа на матрицу?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

У меня возникла такая проблема я не могу перезагрузить оператор умножения числа на матрицу, матрицу на число я умножил верно, а вот число на матрицу почему-то не получилось. Подскажите как правильно написать?

```
 //Перегрузка оператора умножения * матрицы на число :
    Matrix operator*(int a ) {
        Matrix tmp(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

                    tmp[i][j] += matr[i][j] * a ;
        return tmp;
    }//Перегрузка оператора умножения * числа на матрицу
    Matrix operator*(int b) {
        Matrix tmp(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

                tmp[i][j] +=  b*matr[i][j] ;
        return tmp;
    }
```

Comment: Это должен быть **свободный** оператор. `Matrix operator*(int, const Matrix&)`

Comment: Выводит ошибку "too many parameters for this operator function"

Comment: Еще раз по буквам: **С В О Б О Д Н Ы Й**. Т.е. *не* являющийся членом класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить ключевое слово **friend** в объявлении  оператора (вот [тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/8423/) об этом рассказывают), вот примерная реализация :

```
#include <iostream>

class Matrix
{
private:
    //...

public:
    Matrix(/**/) {  }

    // Умножение числа на матрицу используя дружественную функцию
    friend Matrix operator*(int a, const Matrix& matrix);

};

//Это не член класса, хоть и имеет, доступ ко всем закрытым полям класса 
Matrix operator*(nit a, const Matrix & matrix)
{
    Matrix tmp(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

            tmp[i][j] +=  b*matrix[i][j] ;
    return tmp;
}
```